# Spring 3.2.4 can't convert String to Enum in <util:map.../> although 'key-type' is specified

Tags: java, xml, spring, dictionary, enums

I'm trying to define a map bean with Spring 3.2.4 with an Enum as the key type, this way:

```
<util:map id="myMapping" key-type="com.acme.MyEnum">
    <entry key="ENUM1" value="value1" />
    <entry key="ENUM2" value="value2" />
</util:map>
```

The MyEnum class is a trivial class:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ENUM1,
    ENUM2
}
```

When creating the application context, Spring throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:

  Error creating bean with name 'myMapping':

    Error converting typed String value for bean property 'sourceMap';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException:

    Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
    'com.acme.MyEnum'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:

      Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type 
      [com.acme.MyEnum]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

(*formatted for better readbility*)

I expected Spring to convert the String "ENUM1" to "MyEmum.ENUM1", because of the given key type

```
key-type="com.acme.MyEnum"
```

in the mapping bean declaration.

I know how to solve this by doing an alternate bean definition, using `<entry>`, using the full qualified class name of the enum etc... But I would like to build the defintion as described for easy readability.

Is this a known bug or a lack of understanding on my side?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use this strategy for string conversion.

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    ENUM1("ENUM1"),
    ENUM2("ENUM2")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't change the enum I want to use in my real production code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it seems correct how do you use utils-map, but may be the problem is elsewhere.

I don't know how do you inject the created myMapping bean. If you use @Autowired, it is a possible reason why you get this exception. You should use `@Resource(name="myMapping")` instead of `@Autowired`. [See this ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7916).

I have already test it and it works. If you want to see how, I created a sample project and pushed on github. [Follow this link](https://github.com/selimok/working-util-map-example).

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it has nothing to do with injecting the map. The exception gets thrown during the creation of the application context. The bean "myMapping" just can't be created, long before any injection takes place. Which Spring version do you use?

Comment: Ok, saw your Spring version in the GitHub project. Still can't explain why the problem occurs in my project...